# MySQL Selecting a column until number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I want to select from a column until there is a number in the field.
For example I have postcode data which looks like

```
+----------+
| postcode |
+----------+
| RG41 5LY |
| RG7 6LO  |
| SW 1AA   |
| M 3BV    |
+----------+
```

I want to be able to just get the first letters e.g. RG, SW, M. So select the data until it reaches a non-alpha character. I want to do this so I can group it by the first alpha characters

Currently my query is like this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count, postcodeArea FROM Client c
    (SELECT UPPER((SUBSTRING_INDEX(postcode, ' ', 1))) AS postcodeArea
```

It groups based on the column upto the first space

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't 'order by postcode ' serve your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have up to 3 leading letters in your postal codes, you can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) tot, pcode FROM (
  SELECT CASE 
     WHEN postcodearea REGEXP '^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*' THEN SUBSTRING(postcodearea,1,3) 
     WHEN postcodearea REGEXP '^[A-Z][A-Z].*' THEN SUBSTRING(postcodearea,1,2)
     WHEN postcodearea REGEXP '^[A-Z].*' THEN SUBSTRING(postcodearea,1,1)
     ELSE '' END AS pcode
   FROM client
  ) e
  GROUP BY pcode
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Regex in Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, postcodeArea REGEXP /^[A-z]+$/ as postarea_code FROM Client c
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found there is no way to apply regex on SUBSTR_INDEX(). Only way to use regex in SELECT query is like `SELECT postcode REGEXP '[^A-Za-z]' as postarea_code FROM client`. However it returns with 0 or 1 to show if the row matches. In your case it will return 1,1,1,1 because all rows contains a non-alphabetic character. And this doesn't make sense in you case.
Could you describe more about what you want to do? As @san1646 said, why don't you use `ORDER`? Do you mean you want to group `RG41 5LY` and `RG7 6LO` together by letter R? In that case you can use `LEFT(postcode,1)` to get the first letter.